# Get values by array of keys from redis cluster in nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to get values by keys array from redis cluster in nodejs,
and it returns error: "All keys in the pipeline should belong to the same slot" 
this is code:

```
    private GETALL_P(keys: string[], cb: any) {

    var pipeline = this.client.pipeline();

    keys.forEach(function (key: string, index: Number) {
        pipeline.get(key);
    });

    pipeline.exec(function (err: any, result: any) {
        cb(err, result);
    });
}
```

I searched and someone said: it is not working with cluster.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi key operations on a redis cluster need to be on the same node, which is what the error is complaining about.

To force all the required keys to the same node you can use [key hash tags](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags), just bear in mind that if you are doing this for all keys and not just some subset then you're making the use of a cluster fairly pointless.

Comment: Thanks for response. Problem is that data already is saved in redis by different service. I only read that data.

Comment: Do you have to use a pipeline? Non-pipelined should work fine, it'll just be slower.

Comment: yes that error happens when i use pipeline, but non-pipelined throws this error "ERR EXEC without MULTI" .  --> redis.multi({ pipeline: false });